Monty Hall - He wants to win the goats
My friends and I have been arguing over the following situation for weeks:
In a boardgame of Trivial Pursuit between two people, Player 1 reads a question aloud to Player 2: 'Name the top two highest grossing James Cameron films'.
Player 2 knows for certain that the top three highest grossing films are A,B & C. Beyond this, he has no idea of the correct two answers out of the three and will be randomly selecting the correct two answers.
So we have options A/B/C, with two correct options and one incorrect option. Then we have the following two scenarios:

Player 2 mentally (randomly) assigns A+B as correct, and C as incorrect. He provides his two answers aloud (A+B) simultaneously.  There is no option to switch. This gives him a 1/3 chance of choosing the correct options.

Player 2 mentally (randomly) assigns A+B as correct, and C as incorrect. He provides his first answer aloud "A" and asks Player 1 if he is correct.  Player 1 confirms that this answer is correct. He has the option to switch his second answer based on this information. He is now more likely to be correct if he sticks with "B" as his second guess, instead of switching his answer to "C".


In my head, this scenario translates directly to Monty Hall, except Player 2 is aiming for the goats instead of the car. Confirming the first guess (A) is the equivalent of opening the door and revealing the first goat, so if Player 2 wants the second goat, he should stick with (B), instead of switching to (C).
If you’re Player 1, you know which answers are correct, and you want to win the game of Trivial Pursuit.  Would you confirm that the first answer is correct, or would you stay silent?

Welcome! This setup leaves me with a lot of questions. Does the player get a chance to change their guess after the reveal / lack thereof? Do we need to consider cases where the guesser has some prior knowledge of the answer to the trivia question, or only the case when they are guessing (the original Monty Hall problem elides this using a pure guessing game)? The title is also confusing, in the body of the question it seems like both players want to win. Overall, I think this question would be clearer if you removed some of the "flavor" and tried to present it more formally and concisely.

@BenjaminKuykendall I share your confusion.  Speculating, if the first player is not allowed to change their guess, then the issue of whether the first guess was correct becomes moot.

Just reworded, hope it's a little clearer

"Confirming the first guess (A) is the equivalent of opening the door and revealing the first goat ... ." No, it isn't, because the player, not Monty, chose which door to open. Also, you get confirmation in only $66\frac23%$ of the games (the rest of the time you guessed wrong--and presumably have already lost), whereas in regular Monty Hall, Monty shows you a goat in $100%$ of all games.

As long as Player 1 does allow Player 2 to retract a guess, Player 2 has 1/3 chance of winning no matter what Player 1 says or doesn't say about choice A. If Player 1 commits to telling the truth every time A is the wrong choice and then allows Player 2 to "switch", Player 2 wins every game.

The way standard Monty Hall works, the player chooses a door.
This obliges the host to show the location of a goat that isn't behind the door the player initially chose.
The player then gets to guess how the car and goats are distributed in the three locations; if they guess correctly, they win.
The probability at that point is 2/3 that the car is behind the door that was neither chosen nor opened and that the goats are in the other two locations.
So if the player wants the car and they are allowed to change their guess to the other unopened door, they should do so, giving them a 2/3 chance to win.
If the player wants both goats rather than the car, and if it is an option to choose both the door the player originally chose and the door Monty opened,
the player should do that, thereby winning with probability 2/3.
In your trivial pursuit setup, a procedure equivalent to Monty Hall would be that after guessing A (for example), player 2 could ask player 1 to name one correct response that isn't A (that is, player 2 must name either B or C, and must name one of the two highest-grossing films, that is, they must reveal a goat). Then player 2 can win with probability 2/3 by guessing A and whatever film player 1 named.
But that strategy isn't nearly as counterintuitive as the strategy for winning the car. Basically, you have a 2/3 chance to guess one of the films correctly on the first guess, and then you get the second film for free.
If player 1 has the option not to provide the information, then they should not provide it, because player 2 then is forced to essentially just make random guesses about both films (or equivalently, one random guess which film is the incorrect one), and their probability to win is only 1/3.
